# Javascript: Reading a key/value from a nested key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to output the **Category** property as an array from a nested key/value Javascript object as below.

```
var data = [{key: "A", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
},
{key: "B", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
},
{key: "C", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
}]
```

The expected output is as below:-

```
["One","Two","Three","Four"]
```

I tried a few ways to achieve this.
The one I got closest to was with a nested map function as below.
**data** below is a variable containing the Javascript object above.

```
x = data.map(function(el) {return el.values.map(function(ele,i){return 
ele.Category;})})
```

But the output still is an array of arrays as below. I can slice this and just read one of the arrays returned but I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

```
[["One","Two","Three","Four"],["One","Two","Three","Four"],
["One","Two","Three","Four"]]
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will `x = x[0]` do? `x[0]= [ "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" ]`

Comment: @jrook Yes, in the scenario where I end up with array of arrays as mentioned. `x=x[0]` is my only option. But I am trying to see if I can get to the answer in a more efficient way. In a situation where I have a lot of keys. I might be creating a a very large array which I don't really need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could firstly flatten the returned array of arrays and then use `Set` to remove all duplicated entries.

```js
var data = [{key:"A",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]},{key:"B",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]},{key:"C",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]}],
    x = data.map(v => v.values.map(c => c.Category)).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)),
    res = [...new Set(x)];

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @rkadam Thanks, I appreciate it.  (:

Comment: was about to do that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one not-so-cryptic way to do it. Your setup is a little interesting, since there's duplicates, and you appear to want dupes eliminated. An ES6 Set is perfect for that. This gets you the outcome you requested.

```js
let data = [{key:"A",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]},{key:"B",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]},{key:"C",values:[{Category:"One",amount:2000},{Category:"Two",amount:2500},{Category:"Three",amount:3000},{Category:"Four",amount:3000}]}],
    set = new Set();
    data.forEach(val => {
        let v = val.values.forEach ( x => {
            set.add(x.Category);
        });
    });

    console.log(Array.from(set));
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, it will be even better if you would provide a working snippet, +1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the code worked fine, I tested it. (Later) ah I see, you mean to actually set up one of these "snippets". Meh, that's too new fangled for me. Good ol' copy 'n paste,

Comment: This is great. Both this answer and the one above from @Kinduser fell right in the balance of Javascript within my grasp and teaching me something new.

Comment: Glad to help. These sorts of things become second nature after a while. Beyond this you can think in terms of recursion, but that reality is, recursion is primarily useful in interviews. In 2+ decades of front end development I think I can count the actual need for writing recursive algs in JS on two hands and still hold a guitar pick.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
var data = [
    {
        key: "A",
        values: [
            {Category: "One",   amount: 2000},
            {Category: "Two",   amount: 2500},
            {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
            {Category: "Four",  amount: 3000}
        ]
    },
    ...
];

var categories =
  _.unique(
    _.flatten(
      _.map(data, function (item) {
        return _.pluck(item.values, 'Category');
      })
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{key: "A", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
},
{key: "B", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
},
{key: "C", values:[{Category:"One", amount:2000},
    {Category: "Two", amount:2500},
    {Category: "Three", amount: 3000},
    {Category: "Four", amount: 3000}]
}
];


var ans = data.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    return acc.concat(el.values.map(x => x.Category));
}, [])

var result = [...new Set(ans)]
console.log(result);
```